# How to use markes on a line graph in Observable Plot?

Tags: javascript, plot, data-visualization, observablehq, observable-plot

While working with [Observable Plot](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot), I stumbled across the [markers section](https://github.com/observablehq/plot/blob/main/README.md#markers) in the [API documentation](https://github.com/observablehq/plot/blob/main/README.md).

Yet, I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Imagine I have the following mark:

```
Plot.line(data, {x: "timestamp", y: "val", curve: "natural"})
```

How can I add markers to every data point on this line? I cannot extract that information from the API documentation (an example would be nice). Following versions do not work

```
Plot.line(data, {x: "timestamp", y: "val", curve: "natural", marker: true, markerEnd: "circle"})
Plot.line(data, {x: "timestamp", y: "val", curve: "natural", marker: "circle"})
```

*Remark: I am not looking for a solution using an additional Plot.dot.*

*Remark 2: Cross-posted to the [ObservableHQ forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/how-to-use-markes-on-a-line-graph/6186)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following answer was received on the [ObservableHQ forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/how-to-use-markes-on-a-line-graph/6186):

> Markers have been available in main for just a week, but not yet pushed to npm and Observable.
>
> If you need them now, here’s how you can build Plot from source:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/observablehq/plot.git
> cd plot
> yarn
> yarn prepublishOnly
> ```
>
> The files will then be available in the dist/ folder. Upload dist/plot.umd.js as a File Attachment, then create a cell with:
>
> ```
> Plot = require(await FileAttachment(“plot.umd.js”).url())
> ```

Thus, either wait for a new release to be published or build the source yourself at the moment.